# How to round an output step .5 (javascript) and calculate with the output?

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, calculation

I am not very familiar with JavaScript and/or form calculations. The form and script I made after searching the internet about the topic.

How can I round the output (output_abc) in 0.5 steps (1.0 1.5 2.0 … 7.7=7.5 or 7.8=8.0) and where to place it?
How can I (after rounding the output) [input_a] + [output_abc]?

I am open to all suggestions, pointing directions, help.

```js
(function() {

  function calcABC(input_a, input_b, input_c) {
    input_a = parseFloat(input_a);
    input_b = parseFloat(input_b);
    input_c = parseFloat(input_c);
    return (input_a + input_b + input_c).toFixed(1);
  }
  var SUM_ABC = document.getElementById("FORMINPUT");
  if (SUM_ABC) {
    SUM_ABC.onsubmit = function() {
      this.output_abc.value = calcABC(this.input_a.value, this.input_b.value, this.input_c.value);
      return false;
    };
  }
}());
```

```html
<form id="FORMINPUT" action="">
  <p><label for="input_a">input a</label>
    <input id="input_a" name="input_a" type="number" pattern="[1-9]" min="1" max="99" /></p>

  <p><label for="input_b">input b</label>
    <input id="input_b" name="input_b" type="number" pattern="[1-9]" min="1" max="99" /></p>

  <p><label for="input_c">input c</label>
    <input id="input_c" name="input_c" type="number" pattern="[1-9]" min="1" max="99" /></p>

  <p><input type="reset" value="Reset" /> <input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></p>

  <p><label for="output_abc">output abc</label>
    <output id="output abc" name="output abc" type="number"></output>
  </p>

  <p>Here I want to display [input_a + output_abc]</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounding to 0.5, is very similar to rounding say to 2 decimal places etc.

Basically multiple by X, round, and then divide by X..

X = to the rounding spec.   So if you wanted to round to 1 decimal place for example ->  `7.17 =  Math.round(7.17 * 10) / 10`, this would of course give you `7.2`

So to round by `0.5` , X will just equal 2..

eg.

`Math.round(7.7 * 2) / 2 === 7.5`

Comment: I understand the math.round, but it is still not clear to me where to place (html or script) and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is round your ouput_abc as

```
Math.round(output.abc * 2)/2
```

It will give you the output in 0.5 steps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add after the line where you are calling the calcABC function but before that assign the return value from the function to a variable.

`````
  function calcABC(input_a, input_b, input_c) {
    input_a = parseFloat(input_a);
    input_b = parseFloat(input_b);
    input_c = parseFloat(input_c);
    return (input_a + input_b + input_c).toFixed(1);
  }
  var SUM_ABC = document.getElementById("FORMINPUT");
  if (SUM_ABC) {
    SUM_ABC.onsubmit = function() {
      var outputValue = calcABC(this.input_a.value, this.input_b.value, this.input_c.value);
this.output_abc.value = Math.round(outputValue * 2)/2
      return false;
    };
  }
}());````
`````